# How do I replace ".net" with space using sed in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using for loop, with arguments i. Each argument contains ".net" at the end and in directory they are in one line, divided by some space. Now I need to get rid of these ".net" using substitution of sed, but it's not working. I went through different options, the most recent one is

```
sed 's/\.(net)//g' $i;
```

which is obviously not correct, but I just can't find anything online about this.

To make it clear, lets say I have a directory with 5 files with names

```
file1.net
file2.net
file3.net
file4.net
file5.net
```

I would like my output to be

```
file1
file2
file3
file
file5
```

...Could somebody give me some advice?

Comment: Should that be "file4" in the output?

Comment: Also, why "replace with space"? It is removed, isn't it?

Comment: @knittl sorry, I'm not really used to this site, I hope I made it clear about output with edit. About replace it with space, I just meant that because I want to use sed, I need to somehow substitute it, with  sed 's/that_part_i_want_to_substitute//g'

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
for f in *.net; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}"; done
```

*Details*:

- `for f in *.net;` - iterates over files with `net` extension
- `mv "$f" "${f%.*}"` - renames the files with the file without `net` extension (`${f%.*}` removes all text - as few as possible - from the end of `f` till the first `.`, see [Parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)).

Answer (score 1):

This is a work for perl's [rename](/questions/tagged/rename) :

```
rename -n 's/\.net//' *.net
```

The `-n` is for test purpose. Remove it if the output looks good for you

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
 sed -i.backup 's/\.net$//g' "$1";
```

It will create a backup for safeness

Comment: This is not text but filenames

Comment: In that case remove the flag